# How to add HashMap values to List and print the same

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I am trying to add map values to list for my scenario as below.

I have select statement which returns n-no of columns and row, I am storing them into List of Hash Map of type String and pass it to some other method to produce an EXCEL file out of the result.

i am unable to see any data in the list

Please advice where i am going wrong.

```
while (result.next()) { 
  resultValues.put("PARTC_ID",result.getString("PARTC_ID"));  
  resultValues.put("FILE_NME",result.getString("FILE_NME"));  
  resultValues.put("LOC_ID",result.getString("LOC_ID")); 
  resultValues.put("CRTE_DTE",result.getString("CRTE_DTE")); 
  resultValues.put("CRTE_BY",result.getString("CRTE_BY")); 
  value.add(resultValues); resultValues.clear(); System.out.println(value); 
}
```

Comment: first Add the code which you have written

Comment: Show the code for *... storing into List of HashMap of type String and ...*

Comment: while (result.next()) {
    
    resultValues.put("PARTC_ID",result.getString("PARTC_ID"));
    resultValues.put("FILE_NME",result.getString("FILE_NME"));
    resultValues.put("LOC_ID",result.getString("LOC_ID"));
    resultValues.put("CRTE_DTE",result.getString("CRTE_DTE"));
    resultValues.put("CRTE_BY",result.getString("CRTE_BY"));
    value.add(resultValues);
    resultValues.clear();
    System.out.println(value);
    
   }

Comment: Some how i was unable to show my code in the post

Comment: tom you should add this to your posting.

Comment: @tom Always add the code in your Question not in comment

Comment: i would like to show my entire program but if i add that it is not allowing me to post that is why i added in the comment

Comment: @tom: added your code to posting.

Comment: HashMap<String, String> resultValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
   List<HashMap<String, String>> value = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing your Map after adding it to the List. The Map references are all thus the same (and empty)... I think you want to make this change -

```
// resultValues.clear(); // No, if you need another Map... do this
resultValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then to iterate your value List try

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : value) {
  for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("key[%s] = %s\n", key, map.get(key));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ElliotFrisch,  Even i am trying to loop the Map and store mutiple values i should not clean it for every time it chages it values?

Comment: The List will only have many copies of your one empty Map object reference your way.

Comment: yup, I tried it and could able to see the results thank you a tone!

Comment: Now i have my column names and column values in the map, how can i get those values

Comment: Just to add to my comment i have List<HaspMap<String,String>>